# Set resolution when exporting artboards to PNG using script

Tags: scripting, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Sorry that this is so similar to a recent post but I can't find the solution anywhere. I have created a simple script that loops through each artboard in an open illustrator document and exports it as a separate PNG file. All is working well except that I want to set the resolution to 150 dpi and not the default 72 dpi, for production reasons. This is an option that you can set when exporting manually to PNG but I don't seem to be able to set it in the PNG options in the code, although the script runs without errors it ignores the resolution setting. Could someone let me know how to do this, many thanks. Code as follows:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;;//Gets the active document
var fileName = doc.name.slice(0, 9);//Gets the G Number
var numArtboards = doc.artboards.length;//returns the number of artboards in the document
var filePath = (app.activeDocument.fullName.parent.fsName).toString().replace(/\\/g, '/');

var options = new ExportOptionsPNG24();

for (var i = 0; i < numArtboards; i++ ) {
    doc.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex( i ); 

options.artBoardClipping = true;  
options.matte = false;
options.horizontalScale = 100;
options.verticalScale = 100;  
options.transparency = true;  

var artboardName = doc.artboards[i].name;
//$.writeln("artboardName= ", artboardName);
    var destFile = new File(filePath + "/" + fileName + " " +  artboardName + ".png");
    //$.writeln("destFile= ",destFile);
      doc.exportFile(destFile,ExportType.PNG24,options);
}
```

Comment: I assume you tried `options.resolution = 150;`? Another option may be to scale the image up 208.33% (but I realise doing that introduces other potential problems)

Answer (score 3):

After doing some digging I've found that if you use imageCapture you can set the resolutuion. So new script below. thanks to CarlosCanto for providing this link via the Adobe Forum https://forums.adobe.com/message/9075307#9075307

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;;//Gets the active document
var fileName = doc.name.slice(0, 9);//Gets the G Number
var numArtboards = doc.artboards.length;//returns the number of artboards in the document
var filePath = (app.activeDocument.fullName.parent.fsName).toString().replace(/\\/g, '/');
var options = new ImageCaptureOptions();


for (var i = 0; i < numArtboards; i++) {
    doc.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(i);
    var activeAB = doc.artboards[doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()];

    options.artBoardClipping = true;
    options.resolution = 150;
    options.antiAliasing = true;
    options.matte = false;
    options.horizontalScale = 100;
    options.verticalScale = 100;
    options.transparency = true;

    var artboardName = doc.artboards[i].name;
    var destFile = new File(filePath + "/" + fileName + " " + artboardName + ".png");
    doc.imageCapture(destFile, activeAB.artboardRect, options); 
}
```